# Adding mat-icon Button

Tags: css, angular

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="menu.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>{{ title }}</span>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="logout()" >
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

in there home icon button i need to put the right corner so how to do that.How to add inline css to that home icon-button

Comment: please add your code to stackblitz fork it and post link it will be easy to help you

Comment: i only need put that second mat button to right Conner of the menu bar.

Answer (score 2):

Add unique `class` to this button and use css:

```
<button mat-icon-button class="end">
    <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
</button>
```

CSS:

```
   .end{
      margin-left: auto;
   }
```

See here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-pvavjh?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.css

Answer (score 1):

***Try this***

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="menu.toggle()">
        <mat-icon matSuffix>menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <span>{{ title }}</span>
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="logout()" >
        <mat-icon matSuffix>home</mat-icon>
    </button>
</mat-toolbar>
```